# cannot convert value of type'NSDate?' to expected argument type 'String'?

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

Here is code :

Value for Dict from server :

```
  {
  "leave_from" = "2016-10-26";
  "leave_to" = "2016-10-30";
  "user_id" = 327;
  } 

 let date2 = dict["leave_from"] as! String
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
 let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date2)
 self.FromDate.setTitle(date, forState: .Normal)
```

here I am getting the date format as `yyyy-MM-dd` but I want to change to `dd-MM-yyyy` and display in from date Button.
Please help me to find out Solution.

Comment: You are missing some reading of the methods signature. `date` is a `NSDate` object, and `setTitle(:forState:)` is waiting for a String object for the first parameter, not a `NSDate` one.

Comment: Got solution?..

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it all wrong!

At first you are trying to read date with the incorrect formatter. At second you are setting date as a button title, which expects `String`, not `NSDate`.

You should write something like this:

```
// Created variable to represent string you fetch from Dictionary
var dateString = "2016-10-30"

// Creates date formatter instance
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

// Sets date format required to read date from variable `dateString `
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

// Reads date form variable `dateString `
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

// Sets date format required to convert `Date` to `String`
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

// Converts `Date` to `String`
let buttonTitle = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)

// Creates example button (just for presentation needs)
let button = UIButton()

// Sets `String` title for a button
button.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState: .Normal)
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
let dateString = dict["leave_from"] as! String

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let buttonTitle = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

self.FromDate.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState: .Normal)
```

**P.S. Be careful with force unwrap!**

Answer (score 1):

You are using DateFormatter's `dateFromString` method which returns a Date from a String (as the name says). What you want to do is return a String based on a Date, which is why you should use `stringFromDate`.

If you want to change the format of a date, you first have to parse the date with the format as in the JSON, and then simply change the DateFormatter's dateFormat.

```
    let date2 = dict["leave_from"] as! String
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date2)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    self.FromDate.setTitle(date, forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously dateFromString returns an NSDate and setTitle requires a String.

You need to distinguish clearly in your mind: An NSDate is an absolute point in time. It is unrelated to what your watch says. If I call you on the phone, and we both call NSDate () at the exact same time, we get the same NSDate, even though our watches may be hours apart.

Strings are used to *display* dates using some calendar and some format. If you want to change the calendar or format, you use a method that reads an NSDate from a string, and then you use another method that turns an NSDate into a string. That part is missing.

PS. Don't insist on a display format. Use the current calendar to display the NSDate in whatever format that the user wants.